# Html change document's title

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to use this code from here: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/#test4

Html:

```
<script>
$(function(){

  // Bind an event to window.onhashchange that, when the hash changes, gets the
  // hash and adds the class "selected" to any matching nav link.
  $(window).hashchange( function(){
    var hash = location.hash;

    // Set the page title based on the hash.
          document.title = '13213';
          $('title').text("Boo");

    // Iterate over all nav links, setting the "selected" class as-appropriate.
    $('#nav a').each(function(){
      var that = $(this);
      that[ that.attr( 'href' ) === hash ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]( 'selected' );
      document.title = '13213';
      $(this).attr("title", "asdsad");
    });
  })

  // Since the event is only triggered when the hash changes, we need to trigger
  // the event now, to handle the hash the page may have loaded with.
  $(window).hashchange();

});
</script>

<a href="#test1">test 1</a>
<a href="#test2">test 2</a>
<a href="#test3">test 3</a>
<a href="#test4">test 4</a>
```

Can someone explain why `document.title = '13213';` doesn't not work for me ? It does't change the documents title on click.

I tried using  `$('title').text("13213")` including `jQuery` and didn't work either. I have no idea why.

Edit: I changed my code to be identical with the http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/#test4  website where i got the code from.

Comment: check your bowser console.  "$ is not defined"  in your given link.

Comment: @herr how will i do that ?

Comment: I found one ";" is missing in you code. where your $(window).hashchange( function(){ is complete

Comment: `$(window).hashchange();
  
});`  this is how my function ends , where is the missing `;` ? look at the code on my question not my site

Comment: you are closing function above $(window).hashchange(); you has written '})' this required '});' this. and also your http://shiro-desu.com/dataTables/media/js/jquery.js is not found in your link. had you give right path, just check it.

Comment: @herr reload the page, fixed the js , still dont know what ";" you mean , my code is identical with http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/#test4  i just changed it , its identical.

Comment: @herr i just added  a line `$('title').text("Boo");` to try change the title with 2 different ways , but none of them work, the js doesnt even matter, i just use the code as you see it on http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/#test4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63271/discussion-between-herr-and-shiro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both

```
document.title = '13213';
$('title').text("13213")
```

must work fine.
Notice that

```
$(this).attr("title", "asdsad");
```

set title attr for A element

The problem is you not call function in closure.
Change

```
$(function(){ -> (function(){
```

and

```
}); -> })()
```

And everything will work

Comment: also, why would http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/ work ? and my code not work ? its identical codes i just added a line to try and change the title with 2 different ways, if i remove that line it doesnt work either

Comment: i did, and didnt work , also why would it not work if my code is identical to the website i showed you ? that makes no sense

Comment: provide link with result, please

Comment: Ok, problem on your link is — jquery not have time to load, before start executing. So jquery not loaded — code not work.

Comment: Define whole html structure with head and body.

Comment: the code `document.title = 'The hash is ' + ( hash.replace( /^#/, '' ) || 'blank' ) + '.';`  doesnt require any jquery, also why would head/body tags make any difference ? my code doesnt require any .js file

Comment: And code "document.title = 'The hash is ' + ( location.hash.replace( /^#/, '' ) || 'blank' ) + '.';" work fine on your page.

Comment: You do not do what i ask for. I will not help you anymore. Have a nice day.

Comment: im pretty sure i did, but its ok

Comment: Do it and provide link than ;-)

Comment: Ok, now do changes in my answer and move script with this code in the end of page, just before </body>.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="../scr/jquery-hashchange-master/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js"></script> this must be after jquery script line — change place of 4 and 5 strings